# Can I create table and column name following the parameter?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I Just want to create a table and column following the my function which return nvarchar data type, How can i create like that ? Pls see the code below :

```
IF @mode = 3 
        CREATE TABLE TMP(
            TMPID INT,
            [NAMES] NVARCHAR(50),
            [dbo.GetMonthNameOfDate(@date)] MONEY,
            [dbo.GetMonthNameOfDate(DATEADD(M,1,@date))] MONEY,
            [dbo.GetMonthNameOfDate(DATEADD(M,2,@date))] MONEY
        )
    ELSE
        CREATE TABLE TMP(
            TMPID INT,
            [dbo.GetMonthNameOfDate(@date)] MONEY,
            [dbo.GetMonthNameOfDate(DATEADD(M,1,@date))] MONEY,
            [dbo.GetMonthNameOfDate(DATEADD(M,2,@date))] MONEY,
            [dbo.GetMonthNameOfDate(DATEADD(M,3,@date))] MONEY,
            [dbo.GetMonthNameOfDate(DATEADD(M,4,@date))] MONEY,
            [dbo.GetMonthNameOfDate(DATEADD(M,5,@date))] MONEY,
            [dbo.GetMonthNameOfDate(DATEADD(M,6,@date))] MONEY,
            [dbo.GetMonthNameOfDate(DATEADD(M,7,@date))] MONEY,
            [dbo.GetMonthNameOfDate(DATEADD(M,8,@date))] MONEY,
            [dbo.GetMonthNameOfDate(DATEADD(M,9,@date))] MONEY,
            [dbo.GetMonthNameOfDate(DATEADD(M,10,@date))] MONEY,
            [dbo.GetMonthNameOfDate(DATEADD(M,11,@date))] MONEY
        )
```

GetMonthNameOfDate is a function which return Name of Month In a Year.

Comment: Why wouldn't you use a table variable (assuming SQL Server 2005+), or a temp table?  Besides the fact that the data type returned from the function doesn't appear to match the column...

Comment: I just create the function for multi purpose..

Answer (score 0):

Use dynamic sql.

```
DECLARE @sql varchar(2000)
IF @mode = 3 
    set @sql = '
    CREATE TABLE TMP(
        TMPID INT,
        [NAMES] NVARCHAR(50),
        [' + dbo.GetMonthNameOfDate(@date) + '] MONEY,
        [' + dbo.GetMonthNameOfDate(DATEADD(M,1,@date))'] MONEY,
        [' + dbo.GetMonthNameOfDate(DATEADD(M,2,@date))'] MONEY
    )'
ELSE
    set @sql = '
    CREATE TABLE TMP(
        TMPID INT,
        [' + dbo.GetMonthNameOfDate(@date)+ '] MONEY,
        [' + dbo.GetMonthNameOfDate(DATEADD(M,1,@date))+ '] MONEY,
        [' + dbo.GetMonthNameOfDate(DATEADD(M,2,@date))+ '] MONEY,
        [' + dbo.GetMonthNameOfDate(DATEADD(M,3,@date))+ '] MONEY,
        [' + dbo.GetMonthNameOfDate(DATEADD(M,4,@date))+ '] MONEY,
        [' + dbo.GetMonthNameOfDate(DATEADD(M,5,@date))+ '] MONEY,
        [' + dbo.GetMonthNameOfDate(DATEADD(M,6,@date))+ '] MONEY,
        [' + dbo.GetMonthNameOfDate(DATEADD(M,7,@date))+ '] MONEY,
        [' + dbo.GetMonthNameOfDate(DATEADD(M,8,@date))+ '] MONEY,
        [' + dbo.GetMonthNameOfDate(DATEADD(M,9,@date))+ '] MONEY,
        [' + dbo.GetMonthNameOfDate(DATEADD(M,10,@date))+ '] MONEY,
        [' + dbo.GetMonthNameOfDate(DATEADD(M,11,@date))+ '] MONEY
    )'

exec sp_executesql @sql
```